# App engine - raw request body - stripe webhooks

Tags: google-app-engine, stripe-payments

I'm trying to run my node.js app app engine and I am having trouble with stripe webhooks - with the constructEvent, that I need to give a request raw body. Worked on virtual machine but not on app engine.

```
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.rawBody, sig, stripeKeys.webhookPaymentIntent);
```

Says:

```
No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing
```

Comment: Are you using App Engine Flex or Standard? Remember that these 2 have some differences and that depending on them you may or may not be able to tweak the environment so that it's like your local one.

Comment: I guess it is a standard version

Comment: you can make sure of this as it should be in the first lines of your app.yaml file. I insist because the main difference between [Standard and Flexible is that Standard runs in a sandbox while Flexible does in VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments), so settings are kind of different.

Comment: in my app.yaml is nothing but: runtime: nodejs10

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code? I am actually trying to reproduce the behavior you are getting with the example code from [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/examples/webhook-signing/express.js) but was unable to do so.

Comment: Yep, this is one of many tried body parsers for raw:
`app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    let data = "";
    req.on("data", function(chunk) {
        data += chunk;
 });
    req.on("end", function() {
        res.locals.rawBody = data;
    });
    next();
});`

Comment: and then the function: 
`
export const webhookPaymentIntent = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
        const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
        let event;
        try {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(res.locals.rawBody, sig, stripeKeys.webhookPaymentIntent);
} catch(e) {
.....
}
`

Comment: I think you have to use the bodyParser.raw method to get the raw bowdy as exemplified in the [documentation for stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures), I dont think that rawBody is working the way you expect it in your code

Comment: As I wrote - it works elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code that you posted here, I wonder if the last parameter is indeed the value that you wanted to pass to the `constructEvent` function. it reads `webHookPaymentIntent`. I wonder if this should really be the webhook signature secret? It may be that it really is the webhook secret value, but just named a bit misleadingly.

Maybe this is something though you can verify? A simple test would really to be to pass the string literal here to see if that would work first. Of course make sure not to commit that to any source control.

The stripe-node method params are listed here for reference: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/1d6207e34f978d8709d42d8a05d7d7e8be6599c7/lib/Webhooks.js#L11

Comment: Yes,  my faults for naming it that way - still the situation is, that if I run it on virtual machine it runs well but on app engine it won't run. As I did further research I am not quite sure if the app engine can provide raw body.